# Flutter List.generate but in reverse?

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

I have a container that I am trying to print out items form a list, minus the last item in the list. I am using list.generate:

```
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          color: Colors.white,
          child: ListView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
            children: List.generate(
              Provider.of<WeekList>(context).listOfWeeks.toList().length -
                  1,
              (index) => ListTileCustom(
                index: index,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

My problem is when it prints out my custom `ListTileCustom` widget each new item added to the list is added to the bottom and not the top in the view.

[image]

In the picture above the order should be:

- Red Bar
- Red / Green Bar
- Green bar

and when I add new items by pressing the button they should be added to the top not the bottom.

I tried adding `reverse: true` and that gets the order right but moves everything to the bottom and adds a ton of white space above them... Also not sure the scroll will work in the right direction at that point either.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To reverse a list in Dart, you can use `..reversed` method. In the code you posted, that would be: `children: List.generate(/* omitted */).reversed.toList()`.

Another (probably better) solution is to use `for loop` directly in `children`, for example:

```
ListView(
  children: [
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) FlutterLogo(),
  ],
)
```

With this approach you can easily invert the list (and omit one element, like you desired) by changing the loop, e.g. `for (int i = 10; i > 1; i--)` or something.

Comment: thanks so much the for loop worked great. I had to tweak the loop just a little for my needs but it pointed me in the right direction!